# Dual behavior for Class Based View

Tags: django

Let's say that we model university programs, which are divided in tracks. A track belongs to a program. So:

```py
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tracks')
```

I'd like to allow the creation of a track, with the possibility of specifying the program it belongs to, so I can use:

```py
class TrackCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Track
    fields = ['name', 'program']
```

But from the program details, I want to allow the creation of a track for that specific program, so I came up with:

```py
class ProgramTrackCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Track
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.program_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In the `urls.py`, a `pk` parameter is provided, so this will populate the `program_id` correctly.

Is there any way to merge these two views into a single one, e.g. passing a parameter to the `.to_view()` method, or something similar? Because I need to change the list of fields to be displayed before the form is created and I need to know if I need to override `program_id` or not.

Comment: I didn't get your question properly? Do you mean to hide/show fields based on the kwargs pk ?

Comment: @Arjun Yes, using the same view in both urls, telling Django somehow to use the `pk` parameter or not and showing/not showing the program selector.

Comment: you can use something like request.get_full_path() or i think self.object.pk from the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to override your views `get_form` method and dynamically remove your forms field in case the `pk` is passed to the view:

```
class ProgramTrackCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Track
    fields = ['name', 'program']
    
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class=form_class)
        program_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        if program_id is not None:
            del form.fields['program']
            form.instance.program_id = program_id
        return form
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the django forms and override the form's `__init__` method.

```
from django import forms

class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       fields = ['name', 'program']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('pk'):
            form.fields['program'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Now in your view:

```
class ProgramTrackCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Track
    form_class = TaskCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('url')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk):
           form.instance.program_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a FormView for this, in the **init** function of it you can then check against whatever context you decide to use.

```
def MyFormView(forms.Form):
    fields_for_all_options = forms.CharField(label='SomeLabel', max_length=200)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if case x:
            self.fields['somefield'] = forms.CharField(label= 'a different label', max_length=200)
```

Alternatively you could also pass all fields available on the form then hide them in the frontend